# How to compare the size of the solution of the equation and assign the value to the corresponding variable?

Tags: equation-solving

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]

eqns1 = {x^2 - y == 0, y == x + 1};

{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = SolveValues[eqns1, {x, y}]
```

The above equations have two sets of solutions. How to compare the size of two y values and automatically assign the two small y values to y1 and the large y values to y2?

Or how to compare the size of two x values and automatically assign the two small x values to x1 and the large x values to x2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be of use for more complicated situations:

```
eqns1 = {x^2 - y == 0, y == x + 1};
sltn = SolveValues[eqns1, {x, y}];
y1 = RankedMin[sltn[[All, 2]], 1]
y2 = RankedMax[sltn[[All, 2]], 1]
```

> [image: sltn]

You need to look up [**`RankedMin`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RankedMin.html) and [**`RankedMax`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RankedMax.html) in the docs.

In a nutshell, for the list that you have of the schematic form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}`, `RankedMin[list[[All, 2]], n]` gives you the n$^{\text{th}}$ minimum value of `y`.  Shift to `RankedMin[list[[All, 1]], n]` for the n$^{\text{th}}$ minimum value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["`*"]

eqns1 = {x^2/2^2 + y^2/1^2 == 1, y == x + 1};


SolveValues[eqns1, {x, y}]

{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = Sort[%, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
```

this is method one

A friend has provided me with several solutions. Do you have any other ideas and solutions? Or improve the existing method, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

method two:

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]

eqns1 = {x^2 - y == 0, y == x + 1};

{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} = SolveValues[eqns1, {x, y}]

{y1, y2}

{y1, y2} = {Min@%, Max@%}
```